# Strange behavior of jQuery templates with comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

We have a template, that comes from server. It contain commented blocks of html: `<!-- ... -->`. When we apply jquery template on it, some strange `_tmplitem` attribute appears inside of commented nodes.

And when we uncomment that block and apply another jQuery template on it - we have problems.
If before applying second template on that block we do:

```
html = html.replace(/_tmplitem=['"]\d+['"]/mig, '');
```

Everything is cool. What is going on? Could you explain? Any thoughts? And if you know how to overcome it without additional replacing - please tell.

Comment: May have to do with the way jQuery implements templates internally; do you need the comments in there or could you parse them out first?

Comment: Comments should be parsed later, cuz they contain "like buttons", that load lazy.. It's not a problem to do double replacing, but really interesting why we should do that. It's a mistake in implementation or what?